# alternative to return in PHP?

Tags: php, return

I want to run two loops one after the other but it seems the `return` statement in the first loop ends the script:

```
// this runs
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    try {
        foo();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        try {
            bar();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}


// this doesn't
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    try {
        foo();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        try {
            bar();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess you're looking for `break;` -- or you could place it in a function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `return` within a loop, it's meant for functions/class methods.

You should replace `return false` with [`break`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.break.php), the loop equivalent, and `return true` with [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php). However, as John Conde noticed, you could just leave [`continue`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.continue.php) out in this example.

```
function         loop
---------------------------
return true;     continue;
return false;    break;
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `return true` and replace it with nothing.

Or, use `continue`. It will restart the loop from the next iteration.

**update**

Replace the `return false` with `break` as mentioned in your comments